# Angular JS + Button should be enabled if at least one checkbox is checked how To do it?

Tags: angularjs

I want a button that is only enabled if at least one of a group of checkboxes is checked, similiar to the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/chriscoyier/BPhZe/76:

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

checkboxes.click(function() {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

I want to implement this using AngularJs.

Comment: try to be more clear, what's the behavior you're trying to reach? put some code in the answer and after that edit the link, so i can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it is done. I have done it using `grep` in jQuery.

```
 $scope.userSelectionChanged = function () {
        $scope.enableAddBtn = $.grep($scope.userlists, function (user) {
            return user.IsSelected;
        }).length >= 1;
 };
```

Answer (score 5):

Add a function to your controller that checks if any of the check boxes are checked.  If the radio button is checked its value will be true.  Then, in the HTML use the [ng-disabled](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) directive on your button and set it equal to the result of your function.  Example:

Controller:

```
$scope.isCheckboxChecked = function() {
    return ($scope.checkbox1 || $scope.checkbox2 || $scope.checkbox3);
}
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" ng-disabled="!isCheckboxChecked()">My Button</button>
```

It would be helpful if you posted the code you have already tried.  My answer is assuming you already have functional check boxes using the ng-model directive and are just looking for how to disable the button when any of them are checked.

**Update:**

If you don't already have your checkboxes binding to your controller, here is an example.  Note the use of ng-model to bind to a $scope.checkbox1 or $scope.checkbox2 variable in your scope.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox1">Checkbox 1
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkbox2">Checkbox 2
```

Comment: thank you for the Reply  if i am doing the Same thing it is giving me error like checkbox1 is not defined ! What to do  ???

Comment: Please create a fiddle so that I can check where the problem is.

Comment: Do you have a $scope.checkbox1 variable defined in your controller?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that your form consists of a long list of check boxes, then alternatively you can create the list in the Controller's $scope and then iterate each check box items along with specific properties such as its label and its state(model) where it is checked or not. Next is to create a function that determines if any of the check box in the check box list has its state checked(`isChecked`).

[Plunker DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/G72YCsE7E7Jnlw9tt99Y?p=preview)

**Controller**

```
controller('Controller', function($scope) {
    $scope.checkBoxes = [
        {label: 'Option 1', isChecked: false},
        {label: 'Option 2', isChecked: false},
        {label: 'Option 3', isChecked: false},
        {label: 'Option 4', isChecked: false},
        {label: 'Option 5', isChecked: false}
    ]; 

    $scope.isChecked = function() {
        for(var e in $scope.checkBoxes) {
             var checkBox = $scope.checkBoxes[e];
            if(checkBox.isChecked)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
});
```

At this point, you can iterate the check box list in your form and fill up properties(e.g. `label`) and its respective models(`isChecked`) in each check box.

**HTML**

```
<form ng-controller="Controller">
    <div ng-repeat="checkBox in checkBoxes">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkBox.isChecked" id="check-box-{{$index}}" />
        <label ng-bind="checkBox.label" for="check-box-{{$index}}"></label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="do thing" ng-disabled="!isChecked()" /> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you for the Reply  if i am doing the Same thing it is giving me error like checkbox1 is not defined ! What to do  ???  And i also want that id the CheckBox id checked then and then validation of that control should do !! Is it Possible  ???

Comment: please post your current code, or make a fiddle or plunker for me to check where the problem is.

Comment: Add I haven't Implemented the Validation Portion so that i don't know that how to implement it ! so in validation you can help it will also very Usefull for me

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/9tcht/1/ the fiddle i have made according to my code here  data are comming from the Database so at a time more that 3 or 4 check boxes may be available in the Code. Please help Badlly need it !

Comment: I think the problem does not lie in the code. As what I've seen in your JSFiddle, it lacks the requirements to make a proper AngularJS app. It lacks an ng-app  directive, no ng-controllers, and the definition of the controllers as well. I that you try to watch these tutorials from https://egghead.io/technologies/angularjs

Comment: I have just made that so you can have idea what i am doing !! am i doing right ??? or wrong  ??

Answer (score 1):

this could be a solution but it's not easy to understand what you are searching for

## HTML

```
<h1>Button should be enabled if at least one checkbox is checked</h1>

<form>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-1" id="option-1" ng-click="check()"> <label for="option-1">Option 1</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-2" id="option-2" ng-click="check()"> <label for="option-2">Option 2</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-3" id="option-3"> <label for="option-3" ng-click="check()">Option 3</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-4" id="option-4"> <label for="option-4"ng-click="check()">Option 4</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option-5" id="option-5"> <label for="option-5" ng-click="check()">Option 5</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button" ng-click="checkboxes" ng-disabled="enabled" value="Do thing" disabled>
</div>
</form>
```

## JS

```
$scope.enabled=true

$scope.check=function(){
    $scope.enabled=false
}

$scope.checkboxes=function() {

});
```

Comment: Using ng-click on the checkboxes is unnecessary.  If the user simply uses ng-model the value will be bound to a variable in the scope, which they probably want to do anyway if they're going to do something with the value.  They can then check if the checkbox is true or false to know whether it was clicked or not.  Also, they want to disable the button if none of the options are clicked.  Your solution is disabling the button if a checkbox is clicked.

Comment: yes i know, but i wanted put it to let him know the existence of that modules, because it seems to me that he is really new to angularjs.