# angular disable button when array empty

Tags: angularjs

Maybe I'm just not thinking straight. Can I enable/disable a link via my controller using some form of angular ng-click and ng-disabled?

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dxquye40/3/)

```
see fiddle...
```

The 'Do stuff to things' button should not be enabled unless at least one 'thing' is checked, and no action should be taken either. Of course, once a Thing IS checked, the button should activate.

The more I try to fix this, the more complicated it gets, and I can't help but think I'm overlooking something obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Because ng-disabled for INPUT's.

Use ng-class here is an example in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxquye40/6/)

```
  <a ng-class="{'disabled': things.length==0}" ng-click="doStuff()">Do stuff to Thing(s)</a>

 $scope.doStuff = function(){
        if($scope.things.length==0) return;
        console.log('Stuff has been done to things');
    }
```

Comment: I can get it to do it once, but when I return to the page, the button is enabled and the check boxes have no effect.

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan ngDisabled works with button as well.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to remove the curly around your test if you want to do something with ng-disabled. Generally, you dont need to use them with the native angular directive (except for ng-href..)

Afterward, the ng-disabled dont prevent the ng-click if it's not on a button, so you need to use a button or use a syntaxe like this in your ng-click:

```
ng-click="condition && doSomething()"
```

Here is a working example, hope it will help you

http://jsfiddle.net/dxquye40/8/

Comment: I.do.not. understand angular's curly bracket syntax. Sometimes it's double, sometimes it's single, sometimes it's none at all. I don't know what any of them mean.

Comment: it's pretty simple :). The double curly braces declares to angular to interpolates the content as javascript. You can define variables, call functions ...

In a directive you dont need to use them because inside the $parse service is called. The content will be interpolate each time the directive need.

Moreover the somple curly brace is used to define a javascript object. when you declare `ng-class="{active: condition}"` you give an literal object with an active attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Check out ryeballer's answer in this post: [Angular JS + Button should be enabled if at least one checkbox is checked how To do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22863256/angular-js-button-should-be-enabled-if-at-least-one-checkbox-is-checked-how-to)

The plunker ryeballer provided should be modified by flipping the condition in the ng-disabled directive:

```
ng-disabled="!isChecked()"
```

Here's an adjusted plunker:
  http://plnkr.co/edit/N0az5UeVH0VRlGK1ZwvC?p=preview

This seems very similar to what you want to do.

Keep in mind also that the ng-disabled directive doesn't seem to affect anchor tags. So, if you can, use something else (such as a button element ). 
Also, note how your initial solution does not take advantage of Angulars data-binding. Rather than setting ng-click events on your checkboxes, just tell Angular what this data is via the ng-model directive. Let Angular take care of the stuff you've got in your setThing() method.

Answer (score -1):

If you're allowed to use jQuery then you can use .removeClass(), as I did here with your script.

http://jsfiddle.net/kirdua/dxquye40/21/

`code`

Comment: It is not considered good practice to manipulate the DOM within Angular controllers. The only place it is appropriate is within a directive.